# Accidentally ran chown -R / and now mail queue not being delivered

Tags: chown

EDIT:   BTW, everything else including all websites on the server are running fine except that mail queue in whm is not automatically being delivered.   What directory would I need to change permissions on just to fix mail sending again?

So last night I accidentally typed the following command as root via ssh and changed some permissions to account 'userx':

chown -R userx /

That permission change command only ran for about 5 seconds and I quickly realized my error and forced stopped it.

Today the mail queue is not being delivered unless I manualy force deliver all mail in the queue in whm.

I don't know if that was the cause of this issue but a few minutes ago I ran the following command to try fix it and let that run for about 5 seconds then force stopped it.

chown -R root /

However, the problem with the mail queue is still there.

Can you please let me know if in fact that accidental few seconds of changing of permissions in / could be the problem and how can I check which essential directories and files actually got change and need to be set back to root permissions?

Thank you

Comment: Basically, chances are you're screwed. Restore a backup.

Comment: The linked question provides a couple of scripts which you _might_ be able to use to recover the system, but you should plan on restoring from backup.